# Docs Rest API Request and response

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse

This request contains test data for REST Request and getting its response from Docsaway API.This explains how to bind Json object to REST API request and and getting json response in c#.Sending an pdf file as an attachment into  httprequest.

```
 public static void SendRequest()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Connectionchil = new Dictionary<string, string>();// Started to make request object for request with sample data
        Connectionchil.Add("email", "Your Email");
        Connectionchil.Add("key", "your key");

        Dictionary<string, string> recpientchild = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        recpientchild.Add("name", "testname");
        recpientchild.Add("company", "company");
        recpientchild.Add("address1", "Test Address One");
        recpientchild.Add("address2", "Test Address 2");
        recpientchild.Add("city", "Test City");
        recpientchild.Add("state", "TestStae");
        recpientchild.Add("zip", "2260");
        recpientchild.Add("country", "AU");

        Dictionary<string, string> stationchild = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        stationchild.Add("id", "GB2");
        stationchild.Add("courierID", "GB2_2");
        stationchild.Add("ink", "BW");
        stationchild.Add("paper", "80");//End of request  object  for request with sample data

        FileStream fsAttachIn = System.IO.File.OpenRead("d:\\test.pdf");// 
        var streamOfFile = File.ReadAllBytes("d:\\test.pdf");
        string base64PDF = Convert.ToBase64String(streamOfFile);
        JsonReQuestObject RequesetObj = new JsonReQuestObject(Connectionchil, "TEST", true, recpientchild, stationchild, base64PDF, "Testing Seller");
        var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequesetObj);//Serialization of request object into json object


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.docsaway.com/app/api/rest/mail.json");// Started to make HTTP Request
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            streamWriter.Write(Json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        string result = null;

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) //
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JsonResoponseOfRequest ResponseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResoponseOfRequest>(result);//Deserialization of  response into custom classes generated 

        Console.Write("API Error Number :" + ResponseResult.APIErrorNumber + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("API Report start from below\n");
        Console.Write("\t" + ResponseResult.APIReport);
        Console.WriteLine("API Report Ends Here\n");
        Console.Write("Document Details starts here \n");
        foreach (var d in ResponseResult.Document)
        {
            Console.Write("\t" + d.Key + ":");
            Console.Write("\t" + d.Value + "\n");
        }
        Console.Write("Document Details ends here\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Station information starts from here\n");
        foreach (var s in ResponseResult.station)
        {
            Console.Write("\t" + s.Key + ":");
            Console.Write("\t" + s.Value + "\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("station information ends here");

        Console.WriteLine("Transaction information starts here");
        foreach (var t in ResponseResult.transaction)
        {
            Console.Write("\t" + t.Key + ":");
            Console.Write("\t" + t.Value + "\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction information Ends here");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: ... and your Question ?

Comment: What is your question? Otherwise please delete this post.